# Cant able to handle request in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

In my express application I am getting following error while getting request from user. No issue if request body is ib JSON format

```
UnsupportedMediaTypeError: unsupported charset "ISO-8859-1"
    at urlencodedParser (/var/www/payment/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:108:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/payment/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/var/www/payment/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /var/www/payment/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/var/www/payment/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/var/www/payment/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/var/www/payment/gate.js:392:5)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:159:13)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1054:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11
```

)

I already set this in my code

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

`body-parser` [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) say:

> Returns middleware that only parses urlencoded bodies and only looks at requests where the Content-Type header matches the type option. This parser accepts only UTF-8 encoding of the body and supports automatic inflation of gzip and deflate encodings.

I would try disabling (commenting out in your code) the `bodyParser.urlencoded` parser.